# How to retain Fragments of the View Pager on Screen Rotation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have one Activity(extends FragmentActivity).In onCreate of Activity I dynamically create Fragment.In the onCreate of Fragment I set setRetainInstance(true).I also call AsyncTask.execute() to load some list from external server.In the onPostExecute() of AsyncTask I Call this -

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

The no of items in ViewPager are created in such a way- I divide a whole list into small lists of 10 items each and make a listfragment of these lists and assign to pager.

Now When I rotate the screen,my device does not crash but just screen becomes completely white.I took the logs and found that getItem() and getcount() are not called after I rotated the screen.I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

I looked for solutions on SO but could not find appropriate solution.How to retain the viewpager fragments after rotating screen?

Comment: You need to set an instance of your adapter class on the `ViewPager` after the `Activity` is reinstantiated.

Comment: I did this in my onActivityCreated method of Fragment but on screen rotation app crashes

Comment: Oh, so your `ViewPager` is inside your retained `Fragment`? That might have some ramifications. In any case, posting your crash log might shed some light on the matter.

Comment: @corsair992 - I got Null Pointer Exception at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:579)

Comment: @corsair992 - I set an instance of adapter class on the viewpager as you asked me to but I got Null Pointer exception.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

put this in to your fragment class

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```